# How to query a full JSON array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

I want to query a full JSON array in PostgreSQL (as in, check if there's a JSON array in the table matching my input JSON array)

In MySQL I used to do:

```
SELECT * from <table> where <column> = JSON_ARRAY("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
```

In Laravel:

```
return $this->whereRaw("<column> = JSON_ARRAY(" . "'" . implode("','", json_encode(explode(',', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $input)))) . "'" . ")");
```

And it worked fine (even though the code in Laravel wasn't probably the best way of doing it, in which case I'm open to suggestions on how to improve the code). I want to know a query in PostgreSQL that behaves exactly the same way as the MySQL query i've written.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [json functions in Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html)?

Comment: Note that you will also have to change the DB driver etc in your `.env` file if you are switching to Postgres.

Comment: I did look at the JSON functions first, yeah, and I didn't find the one that could match what I wanted. I also changed the DB driver accordingly in Laravel.

Comment: Can you provide ```$input``` and the result that you need?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
select * from <table> where <column> = to_jsonb(array['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);
```